# Inverse Dynamic library implementation in ROS?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use Inverse Dynamics to implement a hybrid Torque/Position on an exoskeleton. My intitial plan is to use a detailed URDF of my robot and then a software tool that can take it and solve for the torque that needs to be generated by a joint to follow the path. The system will have to run on ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS with ROS kinetic

I found a large list of different solvers that can be used, found [here](http://yinglu.me/survey.html)

I have focussed my search on the following four solvers:

- Open Dynamic Engine
- DART
- Pybullet
- Rigid Body Dynamics Library

It seems that all of these methods do pretty much the same thing.
Which of the inverse dynamics solver is best supported by ROS?
What solver is generally used by ROS users?
What are important aspects to take into account when choosing a solver?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314770/inverse-dynamic-library-implementation-in-ros?/) by [bvaningen](https://answers.ros.org/users/39746/bvaningen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2019-02-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From what you're looking at being discrete simulator solvers Gazebo is closely integrated with ROS and has support for using ODE, Bullet, Simbody and DART.

See "Dynamics Simluation" at http://gazebosim.org/

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2021-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0